# How to assign conditional answer into variable in eval() in PHP?

Tags: php, eval

we execute dynamic string IF condition in PHP `eval()` function but the answer is not assign in variable.

Please look below code :

```
$variable_1 = "if(3>4)";
$variable_1 = "1";
$variable_1 = "0";

$if_val = "$variable_1{ $return_if = $variable_2 } else { $return_if = $variable_3 }";
$final_if_ans = eval($if_val);
```

Comment: Aside from your 3 variables having the same name, you can print out the resulting code by printing `$if_val` to see what you're actually running. `$return_if` is not defined either.

Comment: You should be really careful with using `eval()`, it can be a security risk and should be avoided at all costs!

Comment: In `$if_val`, `$return_if` is not defined and also you've missed `;` in each condition which will also throw error.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to get the desired result:

```
$variable_1 = "if(3>4)";
$variable_2 = "1";
$variable_3 = "0";

$if_val = "$variable_1{ return $variable_2; } else { return $variable_3; }";
$final_if_ans = eval($if_val); 
echo $final_if_ans;
```

**Important:**
The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

You declared all variables as `$variable_1`. Change to `$variable_2` and `$variable_3`

Change this

```
$variable_1 = "if(3>4)";
$variable_1 = "1";
$variable_1 = "0";
```

to

```
$variable_1 = "if(3>4)";
$variable_2 = "1";
$variable_3 = "0";
```